# How to correctly return a list of class instances in Python

Tags: python, list, class

```
class ligne():
    def __init__ (self, stops):
        ##stops = a list of instances of Ligne1Stop class
        self.stops = stops
    def returnAllStopsOnLigne(self):
        return self.stops
```

When I call the method returnAllStopsOnLigne() I get a list of

```
"<__main__.ligne1Stop instance at 0x1418828">
```

How can I return the proper class instance names in my stops list?

Comment: Do you need all instances? Description/question is quite tangled...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking at the `repr()` representation output of your classes. `repr()` will call the [`__repr__()` hook](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) if defined on your custom classes:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '<linge1Stop: name={0}>'.format(self.name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Martijn's answer, you can

```
return [ s.__class__.__name__ for s in self.stops ]
```

Of course, if you are interested *only* in class instance names

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to return a string representation for each of your instances is to define a `__repr__` method on your class, like this:

```
class ligne(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return u'<{c} name={n}>'.format(c=self.__class__.__name__, n=self.name).encode('utf-8')
```

Example Usage:

```
>>> L = ligne()
>>> L.name = u'John Smith'
>>> L
<ligne name=John Smith>
>>>
```

The purpose for the `u` and the `encode('utf-8')` is to make sure that your `__repr__` will not break when your `name` attribute is set to a Unicode value (e.g., `Café Del Mar`). This is a common noob mistake that isn't usually caught until production, where it can become a headache. Example usage:

```
>>> type(u'Hello, World'.encode('utf-8'))
<type 'str'>
```

Note also that I subclassed `object`. Not subclassing `object` will lead to a different [MRO](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) than you want or would expect, and that is not forward compatible with Python 3's.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - `UNICODE_OBJECT.encode('utf-8')` *IS* a `str`... argumentum ad infinitum much?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ha, see... argumentum ad infinitum

Comment: Okay, rereading the edits, I missed your `.decode('utf8')` at the end of the line; so for that my apologies. I would still have reverted that edit though; an extra comment would not have hurt in that case. My example was as simple as possible for a reason, to have to next teach about unicode vs. string would have been out-of-scope. I wish you had been a little clearer in your response, you would have received an apology from me sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output you are providing, you are passing in a single instance of the `Ligne1Stop` class. Obviously, this will not give you all "names" of such instances.

What you should do is keep the list of all instances of the class in that class itself:

```
class Ligne1Stop(object):
      allinstances = []

      def __init__(self, name, *args):
          self.allinstances.append(self)
          self.name = unicode(name)
          # rest of init
```

To get all names, you will need to add some way to get a name, and define the `__unicode__` method to use that as the string representation:

```
      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.name
```

Then you can do:

```
[str(instance) for instance in Ligne1Stop.allinstances]
```

You can add methods to return a separate copy of the `allinstances` list if you like and/or hide it behind a property.

Comment: excellent answer, thank you very much. I actually created a list of each instance, and have a list of the outputs I provided (not just the one). Nevertheless you answer is a bit more effective.